# Date less than MySQL query not working

Tags: mysql

I've a table

```
| adsid | user_id | earned_points | redeem_points | dialer_point | app_point | date                |
+-------+---------+---------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+---------------------+
|     1 |       1 | 25            | 15            | 23           | 2         | 2015-03-15 19:38:43 |
|     3 |       1 | 25            | 15            | 23           | 2         | 2015-03-15 19:38:43 |
|     2 |       1 | 25            | 15            | 23           | 2         | 2015-03-15 19:38:43 |
|     1 |       2 | 25            | 15            | 23           | 2         | 2015-03-15 19:38:43 |
|     3 |       2 | 25            | 15            | 23           | 2         | 2015-03-15 19:38:43 |
|     2 |       2 | 25            | 15            | 23           | 2         | 2015-03-15 19:38:43 |
|     1 |       3 | 25            | 15            | 23           | 2         | 2015-03-15 19:38:43 |
|     3 |       3 | 25            | 15            | 23           | 2         | 2015-03-15 19:38:43 |
|     2 |       3 | 25            | 15            | 23           | 2         | 2015-03-15 19:38:43 |
|     1 |       4 | 25            | 15            | 23           | 2         | 2015-03-15 19:38:43 |
|     3 |       4 | 25            | 15            | 23           | 2         | 2015-03-15 19:38:43 |
|     2 |       4 | 25            | 15            | 23           | 2         | 2015-03-15 19:38:43 |
|     1 |       5 | 25            | 15            | 23           | 2         | 2015-03-15 19:38:43 |
|     3 |       5 | 25            | 15            | 23           | 2         | 2015-03-15 19:38:43 |
|     2 |       5 | 25            | 15            | 23           | 2         | 2015-03-15 19:38:43 |
|     1 |       6 | 25            | 15            | 23           | 2         | 2015-03-15 19:38:43 |
|     3 |       6 | 25            | 15            | 23           | 2         | 2015-03-15 19:38:43 |
|     2 |       6 | 25            | 15            | 23           | 2         | 2015-03-15 19:38:43 |
|     1 |       7 | 25            | 15            | 23           | 2         | 2015-03-15 19:38:43 |
|     3 |       7 | 25            | 15            | 23           | 2         | 2015-03-15 19:38:43 |
|     2 |       7 | 25            | 15            | 23           | 2         | 2015-03-15 19:38:43 |
|     1 |       8 | 25            | 15            | 23           | 2         | 2015-03-15 19:38:43 |
|     3 |       8 | 25            | 15            | 23           | 2         | 2015-03-15 19:38:43 |
|     2 |       8 | 25            | 15            | 23           | 2         | 2015-03-15 19:38:43 |
+-------+---------+---------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+---------------------+
```

The following less than date query does not works

```
select * from USER_POINTS_MAPPING where 'date' < '2015-03-17';
```

But when I do

```
select * from USER_POINTS_MAPPING where 'date' > '2015-03-17';
```

It throws back all the rows. What is this happening?

Comment: What do you mean when you say it does not work? Are you sure it's not actually working, but returning no rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try without ' characters (single quotation mark) around date. In MySQL either don't use any quotation mark or use this one ` (backtick) around field names.

`'date'` means date as string. And `'date'` is always greater than `'2015-03-17'` when they are compared as string

While

```
`date`
```

means date as a field name

So the correct query is:

```
select * from USER_POINTS_MAPPING where date < '2015-03-17';
```

Answer (score 0):

Pro tip: Don't use `date` as a column name. It's a reserved word.  If you must use it surround it with backticks, not quotes.

```
where `data` < '2015-03-17'
```